Advanced Placement and Honors classes
This is a good problem to have….
My daughter is an advanced learner. Her freshman year of high school, her lowest grade is 97%. She can start taking Honors classes next year and AP classes as a junior. Although I think AP classes are great for college credit, I have hesitation about Honors.
Her HS does not weight the courses, so it’s the same 4.0 for an A in an Honors course compared to a non-Honors course also receiving a 4.0. Her likelihood of straight As in Honors (or more than two APs) is greatly diminished.
So, Should I let my daughter breeze through HS, graduating potentially as valedictorian and having full ride scholarship offers OR encouraging her to be more challenged at school which would undoubtedly alter her class rank? It is of course possible that she could join the Honors program and still score straight As.

Most US colleges would understand that an Honors class would be harder than the corresponding regular class. Many (particularly state) universities have quite generous tuition reductions based on a matrix of GPA and SAT/ACT scores. And, finally, being challenged is better than being bored (been there, done that).

Your daughter is in high school, so the correct answer is that she should do what she wants to do, with some guidance from you.  "Let" is definitely the wrong word here!  She's old enough to make meaningful decisions about her life, and one of those is to decide what she wants to get out of high school.  No decision here is objectively correct - which is the best kind of choice for someone to make!
On balance, colleges are aware that grades mean relatively little in high school relative to the abilities of the individual.  The massive difference in how different schools rate students, allocate grades, and in quality of class makes it nearly irrelevant to compare someone with a 4.0 and a 3.5 without knowing far more than the college is likely to about a random public school (assuming she's at a random public school and not at Thomas Jefferson or similar).
If the choice is honors classes or easier classes and nothing else changes, most likely the more advanced classes would be beneficial from a purely educational standpoint, if she finds that they are at an appropriate level for her.  It sounds like the odds are that is the case here from what you describe, but it's very hard to tell - each person is different.  Giving it a shot for a year and then evaluating the results is not a bad idea - assuming she can always swap to a lower track next year, anyway, if things don't work out well.
However, there is another thing to consider here: if she would do something else with the time, it is possible that would serve her better.  Band, sports, other extracurricular activities - those might help her more both in terms of getting into a college and in life.  Again, this is really a personal decision she needs to make (and lots of people do both!); but she should think about what she wants to do and what will be useful for her future.

Great answer! One tiny thing not addressed: "full ride scholarship offers". This should not come into play at all (easier said than done, obviously) in anyone's reasoning about daughter's course selection, especially the parent. There are no guarantees in life, so this should not be a factor unless college is out of the question otherwise. This is her life. She should be deciding what she wants to do/take after help with looking at it from all angles.
